# Dealing with ini Files - Add Enivornment Variable

Tags: windows, ini

i am trying to add an evironment variable to a path inside an ini file, the variable is the current username in Windows which can be accessed via %username%.

so i would like to do path = `c:\users\[username variable]\ ...`

Will appreciate anyhelp

Comment: How about reading the documentation for the functions mentioned.

Comment: i did but i did not figure out how to extract the username variable from the output

Comment: Re-read the docs for ExpandEnvironmentStrings().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [ExpandEnvironmentStrings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724265%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)().

Comment: can you pleaase give me some heads up on how to use these function calls

Comment: Um, you call [`ExpandEnvironmentString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724265%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with three parameters. The first is "A buffer that contains one or more environment-variable strings in the form: %variableName%". The second is "A pointer to a buffer that receives the result of expanding the environment variable strings in the lpSrc buffer". The third is "The maximum number of characters that can be stored in the buffer pointed to by the lpDst parameter." If you're having trouble with a specific part of that explanation, please elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

See [WritePrivateProfileString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms725501%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) and friends...

Comment: i couldnt find anythng relevant .. can you provide more details please